# Route two domains to same JBoss instance

Tags: apache, jboss, mod-jk

I have two public websites (foo.com and bar.com) that are pointed to a hardware load balancer.  This hardware forwards the traffic to my server as follows:

**http://foo.com**  ==>  port 7700
**https://foo.com**  ==> port 7701

**http://bar.com**  ==>  port 7800
**https://bar.com**  ==> port 7801

My server is currently an old iPlanet box that defines two virtual servers (foo.com for 7700, 7701 and bar.com for 7800, 7801).  Since the load balancer forwards directly to these ports, everything works fine.

I now need to port these website to an Apache 2.2 + JBoss 6.0 configuration, and I'm currently at a loss as to what the best practice is to accomplish this.

I've already set up Apache to listen on my four ports (7700,7701,7800, 7801) and configured SSL for 7701,7801.  I'm assuming it is preferred to let Apache handle the SSL handshakes and connections.  I have set up 4 Virtual Host entries in Apache, as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:7700>
    DocumentRoot "/htdocs/foo.com"
    ServerName foo.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:7701>
    DocumentRoot "/htdocs/foo.com"
    ServerName foo.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:...
    SSLCertificateFile "/cert/foo.com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/cert/foo.com.key"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:7800>
    DocumentRoot "/htdocs/bar.com"
    ServerName bar.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:7801>
    DocumentRoot "/htdocs/bar.com"
    ServerName bar.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:...
    SSLCertificateFile "/cert/bar.com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/cert/bar.com.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tested this with static content, and both the HTTP and HTTPS connections are working correctly.

For my JBoss configuration, I currently have my applications deployed as /foo and /bar, although I don't know if that should be the final configuration.  What I want to accomplish is this:

Forward all traffic from 7700/7701 to **http://localhost:8080/foo**, and from 7800/7801 to **http://localhost:8080/bar**.  I don't want to see the /foo and /bar in the public URL, though - the user should just see **http://www.foo.com** and **http://www.bar.com**.

Is there a way to configure mod_jk to forward requests to a specific URL?  Or should I be looking at ways to have JBoss host foo.com on port A and bar.com on port B -- and just have mod_jk forward to each port separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `mod_jk` combined with URL rewriting should handle what you need. The `mod_jk` information on workers indicates that you should be able to use mod_jk to forward requests based on URL using the uriworkermap. It's also mentioned that you can have a separate uriworkermap for each virtual host.

I'd also like to suggest that you take a look at [`mod_cluster`](http://www.jboss.org/mod_cluster) - it might have additional capabilities that would help with this.

**EDIT**

Argh. After your clarification (and some better digging), I think there may be a different answer. I am currently using `ProxyPass`/`ProxyPassReverse` to redirect top-level URLs to individual servlets. I've reviewed the [Apache VirtualHost docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) again, and I think that if you combine that with `mod_proxy`, you'll be able to get what you want.

Here's a proposed configuration example that builds on what I have and could meet your specifications:

```
Listen 7700
Listen 7701
Listen 7800
Listen 7801

<VirtualHost *:7700>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/foo
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/foo
  ServerName foo.com
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:7701>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/foo
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/foo
  ServerName foo.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:...
  SSLCertificateFile "/cert/foo.com.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/cert/foo.com.key"
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:7800>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/foo
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/foo
  ServerName bar.com
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:7801>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/foo
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/foo
  ServerName bar.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:...
  SSLCertificateFile "/cert/bar.com.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/cert/bar.com.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

I apologize for missing this the first time. The only thing you'll want to test is to make sure that the URLs for servlet access are correct. The pattern I have in use is `http://{host}:{port}/{WARName}/{ServletPath}`. If you've already tested the configuration with static content, only the proxy setup should need to be added/tuned. I'm not sure if you'll need the `Listen` statements or not; I think you will, as your ports are non-standard.

Comment: I'm not sure URL rewriting will work.  I think the problem lies in the fact that I can't find a way to make JBoss listen on port 7700 to serve up content for foo.war, and listen on port 7800 to serve up content for bar.war.    I find it really strange that JBoss will actually listen on multiple ports, but not allow me to specify the content that is served on each one.

Comment: @Fibber - I updated my answer based on your comment; I think you helped put me onto a simpler potential solution.

Comment: Thank you very much -- that did the trick!  I had to make a small adjustment to the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse statements for it to work correctly: I added a trailing slash to the servlet name - i.e. localhost:8080/foo/ -- without it, JBoss looks for a URI of /foofoo :)